# Chamar C++ a partir de Lua

Tags: c++, lua

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de fazer um extensão de lua com uma blibioteca C++, ou seja, o script lua acessar funções em C++.

Ex: arquivo add.lua

```
-- add two numbers

function add ( x, y )

    CHAMAR AQUI uma função de uma biblioteca C++!

    return x + y

end
```

Grato.

Comment: Vê se [isso](https://eliasdaler.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/lua_and_cpp_pt3/) te ajuda.

Comment: Isso mesmo!!! hoje utilizo JavaScript com C++, mais pelo que estou vendo, dá para trocar por Lua... obrigado.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Parece que a sua indicação ajudou o AP. Por que você não cria uma resposta que possa ser útil para alguém que acesse diretamente este site? Se o fizer, ganha o meu +1 (é só me avisar assim que postar!). :)

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente no seu código C ou C++ você deve declarar esta função com a sintaxe específica para integração com o LUA.

O header "lua.h" define o protótipo lua_CFunction desta forma:

```
typedef int (*lua_CFunction) (lua_State *L);
```

Ou seja, você deve declarar a sua função com retorno do tipo inteiro (int) e que receba um único parâmetro, um ponteiro para a estrutura lua_State.

Tomaremos como exemplo uma função para imprimir uma mensagem:

```
void escrever_mensagem(const char* mensagem)
{
    std::cout << mensagem << std::endl;
}
```

Para que esta função seja acessível por LUA devemos implementar uma interface para a função especificada logo acima da seguinte forma:

```
int escrever_mensagem_lua(lua_State* lua_ptr)
{
    //Obtém o último argumento diretamente da pilha (stack) e
    // o converte para o tipo string (const char*)
    const char* mensagem = lua_tostring(lua_ptr, 1);

    //Faz a chamada para a função previamente declarada
    escrever_mensagem(mensagem);

    //Retorno 0 indica que a função foi executada com sucesso.
    return 0;
}
```

Feito isso é necessário expor a interface que criamos ao código LUA, da seguinte maneira:

```
//Inicia o interpretador LUA em um novo estado.
lua_State* lua_ptr = luaL_newstate();

//Carrega as bibliotecas padrão de LUA
luaL_openlibs(lua_ptr);

//Considerando um script chamado "funcao_em_c.lua"
if (luaL_loadfile(lua_ptr, "funcao_em_c.lua")) 
{
    std::cerr << "Falha ao carregar o script!";
}

//Expoe a interface "escrever_mensagem_lua" declarada em C para o script LUA
lua_pushcfunction(lua_ptr, escrever_mensagem_lua);

//Define o nome pelo qual a interface será chamada em LUA para invocar a função
lua_setglobal(lua_ptr, "escrever_mensagem");

//Executa o script "funcao_em_c.lua"
lua_pcall(lua_ptr, 0, 0, 0);
```

Abaixo segue código do script "funcao_em_c.lua"

```
escrever_mensagem("Olá, mundo!")
escrever_mensagem("Posso concatenar strings com números:")
escrever_mensagem("Teste " .. 1)
escrever_mensagem("Posso efetuar cálculos:")
escrever_mensagem("Teste " .. 1 + 1)
```

Pronto, agora você pode utilizar a maior parte das vantagens de LUA combinadas com o poder de C ou C++.

Observação: Esta resposta é uma adaptação e simplificação do conteúdo presente neste [link](https://eliasdaler.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/lua_and_cpp_pt3/) em inglês.

Todos os direitos são reservados ao autor do código original.